# Maximum induced tree

Tags: np-complete, np-hard

Given an undirected graph $G(V, E)$, how hard is it to decide whether it has an induced tree consisting of $k$ vertices, where $k$ is also given in the input?

Comment: If you are interested in maximum induced forests, that problem is known as Feedback Vertex Set, and is NP-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete. Reduce from **Independent Set** instance $(G, k)$. Add a new universal vertex $v$ to $G$. Connect $v$ with a very long path (only to $v$ not to any original vertex of $G$). And set $k' = k + 1 + \mathrm{length\:of\:the\:long\:path}$, where length of the long path is the number of vertices in it.

Clearly, if the induced tree does not touch $v$ then it either only stucks in the long path or being confined to $V$. So, in order to have $k'$ vertices, it must include $v$ and the long path. Since $v$ is connected to all $V$, the set of vertices in $V$ that are included the induced tree must form an independent set.

Comment: Nice answer.  You could let "very long path" be a path of length $n+1$, and then say that $v$ _must_ be included, hence only an independent set can be chosen from $G$.  Then you have an independent set of size $k$ if and only if you have an induced tree of size $n+k+1$.